# Best way to store and manipulate data with Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I want to find a way to write my data into a file, read it back from the file and sort it, read the sorted version of it.

Basically what I have is:

- name: string
- average: float
- sum: float
- coordinates: list of lists, contains floats. can be variable length for each name

I will sort the entries with respect to average or sum field. Then I will read the name and coordinates in the sorted order.

I tried writing a dictionary of dictionaries to a json; however, I couldn't really sort it after reading it back and couldn't manipulate it as I wanted to. My dictionary was like

```
big_dictionary = {"name1":{"avg":0.1, "sum":0.2, "coordinates":[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]}, "name2":{....}}
```

I also tried csv ); but, I couldn't read the data back with its original data types (I couldn't read the list of lists to a list of lists for instance)

```
big_list = [[name1, avg1, sum1, [coordinates1, coordinates2,...]], [name2, ...]]
```

I know that one option is to use pandas. I haven't tried it yet because I am not familiar with it, and I am afraid losing even more time while struggling with its methods. If you recommend this way, I also need some more information

What should I do in this case?

UPDATE: Also, what about ordereddict?

Comment: *I will sort the entries with respect to average or sum field.* Average or sum?

Comment: What if there are two people with same names? Your dictionary approach will fail then.

Comment: better to use `pandas` sorting operation will be better and easy to use this and later you can manipulate data ( df to csv, json etx)

Comment: `pickle` is your friend: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle, you can sort it first, and save it to file with pickle format, then you can read it back as you want.

Comment: There won't be duplicate names, and I will test the results after sorting with respect to sum and then later average. So they both will be used.

I thought pickle wasn't human readable. I prefer to inspect the file later

For pandas how should I construct my data? List of list or nested dictionaries, or list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a list of dictionaries so you could sort easy:

```
data = [{"name": "name1", "avg":0.1, "sum":0.2, "coordinates":[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]}, ..]
data.sort(key: lambda x: x["avg"]) # or sum
```

Comment: yeah but after I want to write it to a file, then read it into a list of dictionaries again. How would I do it? With json?

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with JSON you could sort your data then write it as a list of dicts rather than a dict of dicts:

```
big_ordered_list_of_dicts = [
   {"name":"name1", "avg":0.1, "sum":0.2, "coordinates":[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]},
   {"name":"name2", ... },
   ...,
   {"name":"zzzzz", ... },
]
```

which will still be in the same order after writing to JSON and reading back in. It's also quite easy to re-order this list, for example

```
list_in_sum_order = sorted( big_ordered_list_of_dicts, key=lambda x: x['sum'] )
```

and relatively efficient since it just builds another list, it does not copy or move the actual data in the dicts